# MySQL stored procedure anomaly: One line gets executed, another skipped?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, that checks if there is a user with the same e-mail address as the input, if not, then registeres one.

**Here is the table:**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `overkill`.`accounts` (
  `accountID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `email` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
  `passSaltedSHA` BINARY(20) NOT NULL ,
  `salt` BINARY(20) NOT NULL ,
  `gender` ENUM('m','f') NOT NULL ,
  `birthDate` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `regTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Here is the stored procedure:**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `overkill`.`registerUser` (
    IN emailIN VARCHAR(64),
    IN passwordIN VARCHAR(16),
    IN firstNameIN VARCHAR(32),
    IN lastNameIn VARCHAR(32),
    IN birthIN DATE,
    IN genderIN ENUM('f','m'))

BEGIN
    DECLARE existingMailAccLOG INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE saltLOC CHAR(40);
    DECLARE regSuccessLOC BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO existingMailAccLOG FROM `overkill`.`accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`email` = emailIN;

    IF existingMailAccLOG = 0 THEN
        SET saltLOC = SHA1(rand());
        SET regSuccessLOC = TRUE;
        INSERT INTO `overkill`.`accounts` (`email`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `passSaltedSHA`, `salt`, `gender`, `birthDate`) VALUES(emailIN, firstNameIN, lastNameIn, UNHEX(SHA1(CONCAT(passwordIN, saltLOC))), UNHEX(saltLOC), genderIN, birthIN);
    END IF;

    SELECT regSuccessLOC AS `registered`, saltLOC AS `salt`;
END
```

**If I call:**

```
CALL registerUser("abc@def.com", "pass", "firstn", "lastn", "2012-01-01", "f");
```

It **inserts a line** into the `accounts` table, but forgets to return the proper values that I **set inside the IF**

```
SET saltLOC = SHA1(rand());
SET regSuccessLOC = TRUE;
```

**How is it even possible? Why are theese lines skipped and INSERT still gets executed, without mistake?**

Comment: Try to run your `SELECT` statement inside the `IF` clause and see what happens: `SELECT regSuccessLOC AS 'registered', saltLOC AS 'salt';`  Look at the quotes!

Comment: Still, gets executed, row is inserted, but returns nothing. When the SELECT is there, without the INSERT, it returns the values perfectly. There is something wrong with the INSERT...

Comment: How do you execute the proc? In `mysql` command line client, in `phpmyadmin`, elsewhere?

Comment: Tried everywhere. From PHP, from command line, from phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "@" in front of your variable names after `DECLARE` keyword. It can cause some confusion, as it is described here: [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference? (Part2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010397/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference-part2) and here: [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)