# PHP + MySQL Forum display

Tags: mysql

I am currently building a simple PHP + MySQL forum but I am having problems with getting the information to show in the correct format.

My current SQL code is

```
SELECT forum_posts.catId, forum_posts.postId, forum_posts.date, forum_posts.message,
    forum_posts.userId, users.userId, users.username, forum_thread.threadId, forum_thread.subjectTitle
    FROM forum_posts
    LEFT JOIN forum_thread ON forum_posts.threadId = forum_thread.threadId
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.userId = forum_posts.userId
    GROUP BY forum_posts.catId
    ORDER BY forum_posts.postId DESC, forum_posts.date DESC, forum_posts.catId ASC
```

The problem I have is that it brings back everything in the right category but it brings back the first result of the category and not the last one.

I simply want the code to show the last reply in each category.

Any help is much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should return a range of rows. Try to limit the result to 1 element. If you sort the results descending, you will get the last item.

```
 ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1
```

I am not sure whether you find the latest entry by `postId` or `date`. If you find it by date, you must start the grouping with the `date`.
But I don't understand why you are sorting the results so much for getting only one dataset.

```
 ORDER BY forum_posts.date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is this what you want? Additionally this could help you: [Select last row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql).