# select max id minus one ( second last row id )

Tags: mysql

Just wondering if there is a simple query that I could use to get the second last record when selecting max id.

```
SELECT MAX(`EventID`) FROM `event`;
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do? Just get the last record in the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select last row in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 13):

You can use:
EDIT: (added Bill's suggestion which is better)

```
SELECT (`EventID`) FROM 'event' ORDER BY 'EventID' DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

OR:

```
SELECT `EventID` FROM (SELECT (`EventID`) FROM 'event' ORDER BY 'EventID' DESC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY 'EventID' ASC LIMIT 1
```

This solution is more general and will also work if your EventID column has gaps

Comment: +1 but you can do this without a subquery by using LIMIT with OFFSET.

Comment: the one with offset is a nice idea :) the second one could return the last eventID -and not the last second- if there's only one row in the table (because LIMIT 2 will return just one row in that case)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT MAX(EventID)
FROM   event
WHERE  EventID<(SELECT MAX(EventID) FROM event)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select max(billno) from bill_information
```

[image]

**solution**

```sql
select max(billno) from bill_information where billno <(select max(billno) from bill_information)
```

[image]

---

This will help if you making billing software.That the billno (primary key with indexed) deleted and you want the billno between the billno

```sql
--213763 billno
select max(billno) from bill_information where billno <213763
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

i did something similar to this

$query_anakuklwsh = "SELECT * FROM anakuklwsh WHERE id=".$row_anakuklwsh['id']." -1";

Answer (score -3):

I actually managed to figure it out

```
  SELECT MAX(`EventID`) FROM `event` WHERE `EventID` = (SELECT MAX(`EventID`) -1 FROM `event`);
```

Comment: Until you come to a sequence with `4, 5, 6`, but `5` was deleted.