# How does SELECT return a unsorted result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was just trying to display the result set of a SELECT query in reverse order when I came by this link:
[Select last row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

In one of the answers it is mentioned that relational databases do not have a first or last row. So my question is if we typed in `SELECT * FROM table_name`, is it necessary that the result set will be in the same order in which the data was inputted into the database?

Also, if someone could tell me how to display the results of the above query in PHP in reverse order(without using any sorting in the query itself), it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no ordering in a table, unless a user-specifies the ordering.  SQL result sets represent unordered sets, unless there is an `order by` at the outermost level.  This is how the language is defined.

So, when you do a `select` with no `order by`, then you are not guaranteed the ordering of the rows.  In many cases, the ordering will look like insertion order, but you cannot guarantee this.

There are numerous things that can affect the ordering returned by a select, such as:

- Multi-threaded databases have independent processes reading the data.
- The underlying page cache mechanism is not required to read the pages in order.
- Deletions and subsequent insertions mix up rows.
- The query might be satisfied from an index, not a table scan.

If you want rows in a particular order, use `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do it in simple way

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC
```

I hope this can help you