# how do i get the latest meta id from database automatically

Tags: php

i was trying to convert text into image with php. Now i've finished it but the script is still getting the image data manually
here is the query code :

```
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$db   = "rc";

$connect=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die ("failed to connect") ;
$connect_db= mysql_select_db($db,$connect);

$grab = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE meta_id="4980"');
$d = mysql_fetch_array($grab);
$meta = $d["meta_value"];
```

in this script i use`('SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE meta_id="4980"')` which manually get the meta_id from database and if i want to convert another text to image i should change the`meta_id="4980"` to another `meta_id` my question is how do i get the latest`meta_id`automatically from database ? any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last row in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ORDER BY meta_id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: use `$wpdb` instead of `mysql_*` .https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Query

```
SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta order by meta_id desc limit 1
```

Comment: the result meta_id is 911 my data is in 910 pls help me sir

Comment: i tried SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE meta_key ="fpd_data" order by meta_id desc limit 1 and it works thanks for your example sir :)

Comment: @IhsanSaputra Welcome