# Fetch Latest Entry In table. Last line in database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

tablea

```
id   value
__   _____
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
```

i want to fetch only latest entry in table (i.e) last value
=>id,value as 5,e

could you please tell me query for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last row in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following select query

```
SELECT * FROM tablea where ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tablea);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id, value
  from tablea
order by id desc
limit 1
```