# How to select last user's message in sql

Tags: php, mysql

**I'm making a chat system like Facebook or Twitter**.

Everything is okay but i don't know how to select last user's massage that the user has sent or received from them. I mean when you enter the message in Facebook you can see the last messages that you've seen or not seen.

There is img to explain more below.

I have a table named message having columns like below

`(id,userTo,userFrom,message,date)`

**for example :-**

[image]

Comment: Just order by id desc to get the most recent. Question is pretty broad tho

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE USERID = X ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: which userID you mean? i have 'userTo,userFrom'

Comment: Can I recommend you look up WebSockets for chat applicaitons. There are better methods out there than a typical INSERT and SELECT method with a database http://socketo.me/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the last messages from user X you can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM message
WHERE userTo = xxx OR userFrom = xxx
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT yyy
```

xxx should be the ID of said user.

yyy is a number; to limit the number of messages to appear, if you need such thing.

Comment: i want to get all last msgs not only for one person

Comment: @amr that's not clear in the original question. Check the edited answer.

Comment: yeah that what i want and what i did but it's not working because let's suppose that the user2 send to user1 message how user1 get that in last message

Comment: @amr good point. With that "or" I just edited, you should get ALL messages from that user being the sender or recipient.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from message
 group by userto  order by date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's the actual correct way.

If you have a "id" with a primary key which has an auto increment.

You can just simply do

select (*) from {table name} where userFrom = "NAME" order by id desc;