# How to fetch latest row from Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned table:

```
ID      Date                    Value
AL-1    2017-04-01 22:04:08     154
AL-1    2017-04-05 15:08:45     158
AL-1    2017-04-06 18:09:15     225
AL-1    2017-04-08 20:08:17     254
AL-2    2017-04-01 22:04:08     154
```

I am trying this: `select ID, Value from table1 where id in ('AL-1','AL-2') and group by max(date(Date));` but it gives me output like:

```
ID      Date                    Value
AL-1    2017-04-01 22:04:08     154
AL-2    2017-04-01 22:04:08     154
```

Desired Output:

```
ID      Date                    Value
AL-1    2017-04-08 20:08:17     254
AL-2    2017-04-01 22:04:08     154
```

Comment: `ORDER BY \`Date\` DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two rows with the same latest timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Comment: FWIW, I'm increasingly of the opinion that these sorts of 'intelligent' ids that have some meaning beyond the scope of the database just cause trouble further down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *correlated* `subquery` if you want to fetch latest row for each `ID`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where Date = (select max(t2.Date) from tabel1 t2 where t1.ID = t2.ID);
```

Comment: Or join on a non-correlated sub-query : `SELECT id, MAX(date)` *(which I believe MySQL performs better with)*

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query that returns each id with its max date. `JOIN` with that result:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Value, t1.date
from table1 t1
join (select id, max(Date) maxdate
      from table1
      where id in ('AL-1','AL-2')
      group by id) t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and date(t1.Date) = date(t2.maxdate)
where t1.id in ('AL-1','AL-2')
```

Comment: External `WHERE` is redundant as it is also resolved by pushing the join predicate down in to the sub-query's `WHERE` clause.  *(Or vice versa, I'd probably keep just the external `WHERE` clause and remove the internal `WHERE` clause.)*

Comment: @MatBailie, I kept it because I don't know MySQL optimization very well. Will it make any performance difference?

Comment: None, if you removed the inner `WHERE` then it would be like joining on a view; predicate-push-down, macro-like-expansion, whatever.  If MySQL can't handle this then it can't handle views ;)

Comment: @jarlh It's taking too much time to run the query.

Comment: Add table and index definitions to the question. And the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by desc` with `limit`

```
select ID, Value from table1 order by date desc limit 1
```

Comment: you can add where or where IN

Comment: but when i am writting limit 1 it returns only 1 row.

Comment: @Roy1245 - You only asked for one row...  If you want more than one row, update your question with a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.date =(SELECT MAX(date) FROM table )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ID, Value 
from table1 
where id='AL-1' 
group by date desc 
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DATE ORDER BY DATE DESC SEPARATOR '##'),'##',-1) AS DATE, VALUE
FROM table1 GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.