# How select the last value from a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this table:

[image]

and I need to get the last written value, that is, the last id of the table

How can I get it?

Comment: By the `id` or by the `create_date`? You could just `ORDER BY [id] DESC` and `LIMIT 1`, among other solutions.

Comment: any option is valid, I need the last

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL or Postgres, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.create_date desc
limit 1;
```

This assumes that you want one row, even if more than one row has the same maximum `create_date` in the table.

Normally, `id` would increase along with the `create_date`, so this probably does what you want:

```
select max(id)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can find the latest record in your table using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE create_date = (SELECT MAX(create_date) FROM yourTable);
```

This would return multiple records, in the case of two or more records being tied for having the latest `create_date`.

If you are using Postgres or MySQL version 8 or later, then we can also use analytic functions here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY create_date) DESC rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

We can also replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` in case we want to get ties here as well.

Answer (score -1):

you can use juery ajax to get the last inserted id in mysql table
like the query as

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('khan', 'shan', 
'john@example.com')"

if($conn->query($sql))  // $conn as connection link
$last_id = $conn->insert_id; //will return last id
```