# Getting ID after row insert in Mysql on Google App Engine

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

I am building an application on Google App Engine in Python that uses mysql. When I insert a new row in a table with autoincrement, I need to retrieve the autogenerated ID. Several posts, including the following two, have suggested using "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();", but that does not work.

[PHP/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

[Query-getting last inserted row id in mysql using query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759195/query-getting-last-inserted-row-id-in-mysql-using-query)

What I get when using that command is instead the first of all IDs. My code looks like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tablename (val1, val2) VALUES ("foobar", 42);")
last_id = cursor.execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
```

Is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is correct but the Python is not. `cursor.execute()` returns the number of rows affected, not the result of the operation. You need to call `cursor.fetchone()` to get the actual result, which will be a tuple.

Comment: Thanks, this did solve it. For the purpose of clarity, here is the final code (apologies for the missing line breaks):  <br/>
`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tablename (val1, val2) VALUES ('foobar', 42);")  <br/>
cursor.execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM tablename")  <br/>
last_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]`