# Pre filled fields in form without ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, oop

This is my first project. I want, when I update my record at that time in form all fields are pre filled with previous data.Which are stored in table.

This is my Function code:-

```
    public function getData($query)
      {        
    $result = $this->connection->query($query);
    if ($result == false) {
        return false;
    } 

    $rows = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

This is my html file code:

```
      <?php
      $result = $crud->getData("SELECT * FROM creative_workshop ");
      foreach ($result as $res) {
      $id = $res['id'];
      $title = $res['title'];
      $message = $res['message'];
      $title1 = $res['title1'];
      $message1= $res['message1'];
      $image1= $path .$res['image1'];
      $title2 = $res['title2'];
      $message2= $res['message2'];
      $image2= $path .$res['image2'];
       }
       ?>
<form name="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="title" value="<?php echo $title;?>">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" value="<?php echo $message;?>">
 </form>
```

Comment: Use Ajax for this

Comment: no Without ajax

Comment: can you print `$result ` to check what's there?

Comment: ok wait i will try

Comment: Hey Buddy when i print the Result Am getting same thing like $ result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no value attribute for Textarea.
you can use. Like

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="title" ><?php echo $title;?></textarea>
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" ><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: just check $result have any data. using print_r

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in this line of statement

```
$result = $crud->getData("SELECT * FROM creative_workshop ");
```

Make sure the member function `$crud->getData` is working properly, getData is not returning the fetched results

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

What you are currently doing on your form is getting all rows from your table and looping over them to eventually take the last row returned and show it in your form.

Unfortunately, you get no guarantees from your DB that your data will come back in a [certain order](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5775).

This means that looping over the results from your `SELECT` may return the last row entered but it is not guaranteed.

Instead you want to go and either select your rows with an `ORDER BY` or, and this would be more efficient, add a where to get a specific row.

If you have an auto incrementing ID field you could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21683753/635522).

**Second:**

To show data in a `textarea` field you need to echo it into the tag content, not the attribute, ie:

`<textarea><?php echo $text ?></textarea>`

**Third:**

Echoing text directly from your datasource (in your case your DB table) to the page is insecure.

You should consider escaping it to avoid undesired behaviour - specifically, having HTML in the data rendered.

Imagine `$text` was this:

`</textarea><script>alert('uh-oh');</script>`

Parsing that into the form would make the resulting HTML on the page look like this, thus causing a but of JS being executed on your page.

`<textarea></textarea><script>alert('uh-oh');</script></textarea>`

Avoid this behaviour by using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

`<textarea><?php echo htmlentities($text) ?></textarea>`

With that the output becomes:

`<textarea>&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('uh-oh');&lt;/script&gt;</textarea>`

Looks daft but stops the browser from rendering the content as HTML, thus securing your form :-)