# In Firebird, how to return the ids of the deleted rows?

Tags: sql, database

I would like to return the ids which have been deleted by a DELETE query.

On Stackoverlow, I found this:
[How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

The top1 answer has a very nice solution, but it's for mysql. I tried to do the same in Firebird after reading some part of the Firebird manual:

```
set term ^ ;

EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE uids BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT;
begin
    DELETE FROM CATEGORY WHERE name = 'Haló'
    AND ( SELECT id INTO :uids );
    SELECT @uids;
end
^
```

Yes, I know that 'uids' will always contain one ID, since I'm overwriting the variable, but it's only a test, and what is more, it doesn't work. It stops at 'INTO' saying "Token unknown - line 8, column 21". I don't know what to do, what to continue with.. :\

Thanks for Your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, please run separate queries

1. First fetch the record ids those you want to delete by the same where condition for DELETE

like, `SELECT ID FROM CATEGORY WHERE name = 'Haló'`

1. Then delete the records

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it is the only way. Anyway this was my first idea, but I thought it would be slower because of the SELECT query.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the "RETURNING" clause, like this:

```
delete from Scholars
  where firstname = 'Henry' and lastname = 'Higgins'
  returning lastname, fullname, id
```

[look here for more details](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-delete.html)

Comment: This is true only if `DELETE` statement __removing at most one row__.