# PHP/MySQL error while trying to create MySQL variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this code in PHP:

```
mysql_query("SET @update_id:=NULL");
echo mysql_error();
```

And this is what I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Also this same code runs perfectly in PHPMyAdmin. What am I doing wrong?

Additional information. I'm trying to write a query described here:
[How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)
But the problem right now is that I even can't run a simple query to create variable.

P.S. Ok, now it seems that it desn't work because of some previous queries that are not related to this one. If i move this query to the top of the php file it works. Also if I try to make this:

> mysql_query("SET @update_id:=NULL; SELECT @update_id;");
>   It fails with syntax error. But this works fine:
>   mysql_query("SET @update_id:=NULL;");
>   mysql_query("SELECT @update_id;");
>   Does somebody knows what am I missing here?
>   Why can't I run two commands in one query and why they're the separate queries are related to each other?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE your_table SET update_id=NULL");
```

Comment: And the last updated row could be find like described here: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

**Check this it may be helpful**

```
SELECT @update_id IN("SET @update_id:=NULL");
```