# Update Statement with Select sub select

Tags: mysql

How can I make this work - gives me #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Orders' for update in FROM clause

```
Update Orders set flag = 0 where orders_id = (select orders_id from orders ORDER BY orders_id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Try `Update Orders set flag = 0 where orders_id = (select min(orders_id) from Orders);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a subquery (*creating a temporary table*)

```
Update Orders 
set flag = 0 
where orders_id = 
    (
        SELECT x.orders_id
        FROM
        (
            select orders_id 
            from orders 
            ORDER BY orders_id DESC 
            LIMIT 1
        ) x
    )
```

or

```
Update Orders 
set flag = 0 
where orders_id = 
    (
        SELECT x.orders_id
        FROM
        (
            select MAX(orders_id) orders_id 
            from orders 
        ) x
    )
```

Comment: It should be MAX in your seconds query as OP is ordering it by desc

Comment: @AnandPhadke because you need to create a temporary table for it. I'll show an example for you. Please wait :)

Comment: @AnandPhadke [See the demo. try to uncomment the commented query (which is the same as your query) and it will not build.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b884/1)

Comment: @JohnWoo Can you tell me how I can get the last_insert_id to work with this update statement, I know it has something to do with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) but its not working for me!

Comment: @ManishPradhan try `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: @JohnWoo , i tried but it does not work, may be I am putting it in the wrong place. I put it at the end..?

Comment: actually `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works on `INSERT` statements.

Comment: @ManishPradhan [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying up update the last order in the table? try

```
Update Orders set flag = 0 ORDER BY orders_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Mysql doesn't support updating a table while using it in a subquery..

Comment: Why is there a minus vote on this answer, can anyone explain because it works just fine..?

Comment: yeah I was curious as to the downvote?  it avoids creating the temp table, and the sub select, and just does it all in 1 update.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can get the last_insert_id to work with this update statemtent, I know it has something to do with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) but its not working for me!

Comment: not sure exactly what you are asking?  Last_insert_id doesn't mean anything on updates? especially if part of an on duplicate key

Comment: OK let me explain, like you said, I am trying to update the last order in the table. Your query does that nicely but I also need the ID of the last row that was updated. Is it possible with your sql query by adding something to it?

Comment: never tried, but the technique listed here should help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql

Comment: This worked - Update Orders set flag = 0, orders_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(orders_id) ORDER BY orders_id DESC LIMIT 1;