# Seeking an efficient way to find which rows have been affected by a mysql UPDATE operation

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `field` = 'value' WHERE `item_id` IN (comma separated list of item_ids)";
```

If I execute the above query, how can I find out which item_id's where updated? Note that some of the id's in the comma separated list of item_ids do not exist in the 'table' otherwise the answer would be trivially every id in the comma separated list.

I am using the mysql api where you connect via mysql_connect().

Comment: If you're only concerned to find which IDs exist, why not `SELECT item_id FROM \`table\` where item_id IN (...)`?

Comment: You didn't specify which MySQL API you're using.

Comment: True eggyal in this case, but I also have more complicated queries where that isn't the case. If I can find an answer to this query I could apply it to my other queries.

Comment: @MrCode I am just using a standard WAMP stack. I'm not sure what you mean by API I will investigate

Comment: @Hardworker there are several MySQL API's: `mysql_*`, MySQLi, PDO etc etc.

Comment: You have taught my something new. I am using the msql api (where you connect via mysql_connect() )

Comment: This will help you lost please visit 


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql

Answer (score -2):

use `mysql_affected_rows()`. it will return the table's incremented id's array which are affected in the last query.

Comment: That will give the number of rows affected, not the IDs of each row affected.

Comment: @MrCode yes You are right. Searching to get the answer for OP.