# get a mysql variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I'm trying to use the answer given at : [How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

I want the ID of the row which was updated. But the following doesn't work giving the error 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object`.

```
$query = "
  SET @update_id := 0;
  UPDATE locations SET owner_player_id='$player_id', id=(SELECT @update_id := id)
   WHERE game_id='$game_id' LIMIT 1;
  SELECT @update_id;
  ";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$location_id = $row['update_id'];
```

Thanks

Edit:

$mysqli->error gives `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE locations SET owner_player_id='5', id=(SELECT @update_id := id) WHERE gam' at line 1`

Comment: This indicates that the query is apparently failing .. you need to do some kind of error checking

Comment: is your id column is an autoincrement ?

Comment: yes `id` as in `locations.id` is auto-incremented, but it is not used in this query I don't think.

Comment: have you tried `$location_id = $row['@update_id'];` and try using `$mysqli->multi_query`

Comment: @legendinmaking just read your comment, you are correct but have just posted the answer below before reading, thanks anyway, also had to use `mysqli::next_result` and `mysqli::store_result` to get the right data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to use `mysqli::multi_query` not `mysqli::query`. Also then have to use `mysqli::next_result` and `mysqli::store_result` to get the correct data.

```
$query = "SET @update_id := 0; UPDATE locations SET owner_player_id='$player_id', id = ( SELECT @update_id := id ) WHERE game_id='$game_id' LIMIT 1; SELECT @update_id;";
$mysqli->multi_query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
$mysqli->next_result();
$mysqli->next_result();
$result = $mysqli->store_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$location_id = $row['@update_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has failed, that is why your subsequent `fetch_assoc()` method is also failing.

You will want to look into running your query without using the variables (`@update_id`) as you are intending, and look at using [mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Without knowing what it is you are trying to do exactly, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: The query `UPDATE locations SET owner_player_id='$player_id' WHERE game_id='$game_id' LIMIT 1` appears to work, it's the just use of the code from the stackexchange answer in the link given above which stumps me because I'm not a MySQL guru, also `$location_id = $mysqli->insert_id;` does not work because `$mysqli->insert_id` only works with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, see php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php I've already fell victim to that :p

Comment: If you are wanting to get the `id` of the item you've just updated, you will want to select again. Is there a reason your `id` is not AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: `locations.id` is auto-incremented, but is the auto-incrementation being used within this query? or does that not matter?

Comment: The `insert_id` *should* return the `locations.id` value corresponding to the row you updated.

Comment: Can you see why this doesn't work then? `$query = "UPDATE locations SET owner_player_id='$player_id' WHERE game_id='$game_id' LIMIT 1";
          $mysqli->query($query);
          $location_id = $mysqli->insert_id;` Thanks

Comment: And you are sure that a row is being updated? What's `$mysqli->affected_rows` have?

Comment: the row is being updated, i checked it in phpmyadmin, and `$mysqli->affected_rows` gives the right answer. should i be using that instead?

Comment: sorry `$mysqli->affected_rows` gives 1, which is the correct number, (i got confused because i flushed the database and the ID i was expecting was also 1)