# How to get the last updated row using a single query

Tags: mysql

I searched enough before posting it.

**My table structure:**

> aid | bid | cid | did |

Where `aid`, `bid` together are the **primary keys**.

When I update the value of `cid` using a `where clause for aid, bid` I also want to get the `did value` of the `updated row`.

**Something like this:**

```
$this->db->set('cid', 1, FALSE)
        ->where(array(
                    'aid'   => $a_id,
                    'bid'   => $b_id
                ))
        ->update('my_table')
        ->select('did');
```

**The above query says:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in...

**I tried this:**

> [How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

Which is like 3 queries.

Comment: Why is it a problem to use more queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest fetching the values you're about to update, store their IDs in an array, and run an `UPDATE` with a `WHERE id IN (1, 2, ...)`.

What you're trying to do is not supported by MySQL. You'll need to run at least 2 queries, and since you're fetching the values the first time and already know what values you're updating, then you can also recreate the new row and it's values without using a query after `UPDATE`.

In your given example:

```
$this->db->set('cid', 1, FALSE)
        ->where(array(
                    'aid'   => $a_id,
                    'bid'   => $b_id
                ))
        ->update('my_table')
        ->select('did');
```

`set()`, `where()` and also `select()` returns an object that builds on the query. However `update()` return a value which is the results and doesn't have a function called `select()` and not `set()` and `where()` for that matter.