# MYSQL-Insert value in first empty row of column and read other values in same row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql statement that will insert a value to the first empty cell (first empty row in column). And if I ran the php script again, then it inserts into the next null cell etc.
Problem: I also want to find out the ID of that row, and value of another column in that row. In the Mysql table below, I want a value inserted in the first `null` of `COLUMN A`, and also know the id and value in `COLUMN B` corresponding to that row (ie `id=3 and COLUMN B= 11`).

```
My_TABLE   
ID----  COLUMN A ---- COLUMN B  

1-------    6 -----------------        78  
2 ------   7  -----------------       90  
3 ------   NULL-------------      11  
4 ------   NULL-------------      5  
5  ------  NULL ------------     123
```

The following sql statement in PHP script will make it possible to insert value to the first empty cell in `COLUMN A`:

```
UPDATE My_TABLE  
SET COLUMN A = 83  
WHERE COLUMN A IS NULL  
LIMIT 1;
```

Result will be:

```
My_TABLE   
ID----  COLUMN A ---- COLUMN B  

1-------    6 -----------------        78  
2 ------   7  -----------------       90  
3 ------   83----------------      11  
4 ------   NULL-------------      5  
5  ------  NULL ------------     123
```

I also want to have an sql script that will print within PHP (echo) the values of ID and `COLUMN B` values corresponding to the first `COLUMN A` null value (ie `ID= 3; COLUMN B= 11`).
How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1751282/689579

Comment: "*first empty row in column*" does not make any sense. Rows aren't "inside" columns and there is no such thing as the "first row" either in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the result of the following query before the update query:

```
SELECT ID, COLUMN B FROM My_TABLE
WHERE COLUMN A IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
```