# Get id of updated row in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I updated a row in database using PDO.

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE product SET price=? WHERE seller=?");
             $stmt->execute(array(456,"Apple"));
```

This didn't worked for me

```
$updated_id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

How can i get the id of that updated row.

Comment: There is only 1 product with seller = Apple

Comment: oh okay, i don't think you can get those ids in one query, you need to select those, last insert id pertains to the last insertion

Comment: just select id first, then update (or vice versa)

Comment: Yes i did the same ,it worked.
I have 6 rows in the table.Now i want to query and find the products whose status = 1 and then among them i want to assign "Apple" to first result.How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best you can do is use `PDO::rowCount()` to get the number of rows affected. Remember, your update statement may not update only one, so, there is no way to just get a single id.

Comment: In my case only one row will be updated,show is there any solution?

Comment: If you know one row is to be updated, you can re-query using the data you supplied to it. select id from product where price = ? and seller = ?;

Comment: Yes it worked,i did the same.
I have 6 rows in the table.Now i want to query and find the products whose status = 1 and then among them i want to assign "Apple" to first result.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this answer 
[How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

or do a select on same where clause (If you think it will have only one record)

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id FROM product WHERE seller=:seller");
$stmt->bindParam(':seller', $sellerName, PDO::PARAM_STR)
$row =$stmt->fetchObject();
echo $row->id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$sql="Update table_1 set col_1=?,col_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(col_id) where col_2=? limit 1;SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() last_update_id;";
$stmt =$dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('new_val','cond_val'));
$stmt->nextRowset();
$rez=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($rez);
```

Comment: FYI,  `$dbh->lastInsertId();` with just update query will be enough

Comment: Tested before posting ... And didn't work. Maybe depends on db driver.