# Unable to fetch the order id through last updated tracking id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, nested, subquery

I have this query to fetch the order_id from order_history table like this

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(`order_id`) FROM `".DB_PREFIX."order_history` WHERE trackcode = '".$trackcode."'";
```

Situation is ...

> When Order is packed the tracking id is assigned to it and added at order_history table. If the order has been send by the other courier service there will be another entry for the same order_id in order_history table. But As per above query it will fetch the order_id for that tracking_no. even it was change at order history table.

Another case :- If the tracking no. wrongly assigned to the order and then changed. hence two order_id will be fetched via this above query.

How could i find the correct way to solve it ?

order_history table is like this

```
CREATE TABLE `order_history` (
  `order_history_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_status_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `notify` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `trackcode` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `carrier` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `warehouse_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `logistic_partner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_area_code` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dest_service_center_code` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `added_by` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_history_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=130306 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How Ever I tried this one

```
SELECT order_id FROM order_history WHERE trackcode='11171920880' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 1
```

But it's fetching the order_id even the recently updated tracking code for the same order_id is '1117192089'

My Question is extended one of this one .. its not my solution

[How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

Comment: what's the schema of order_history?

Comment: I have updated the question and provided the schema there.

Comment: `echo mysql_num_rows($sql);`

Comment: You should `GROUP BY` your query, i.e `GROUP BY order_id` in order to avoid fetching more than 1 result.

Comment: The Real thing is I want the recent result @bodi0

Comment: Some how i found this 


SELECT id, timestamp FROM updates ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1

but it's not working for mycase. As I also want to prevent fetching the order_id by wrong tracking no.