# Select the last affected rows

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I have updated my records based on specific condition after that I want to know the ids from the affected rows.

```
$sql = mysqli_query("update table set xxx='".$x."' where yyy='".$y."'");
```

Now after executing this query I want to know the affected rows.

Comment: The number is available in `mysqli_affected_rows`, the rows (and id's) themselves you would have to select in another query.

Comment: @jeron i need the records brother

Comment: Side note: you seem to be fighting against syntactic sugar. How about `'UPDATE foo SET xxx=?, yyy=?'`? Even `"UPDATE foo SET xxx='$x', yyy='$y'"` is more readable.

Comment: if nothing else works, you can always send a `select * from table where yyy=...` before the update.

Comment: As your where column is unchanged in update so you can use the same where clause to get the id's .`"Select id from table where yyy='".$y."'"`

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: It is not a dupe of that question, because this query could update multiple records—whereas the question you have closed against asks only about a single record.

Comment: @eggyal - I think it's pointless to copy here all the answers that explain how to extend it to several IDs but I don't feel like arguing.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I browsed the answers to that question but couldn't see a single one that explains how to do that :(

Comment: Please check [the second part of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1751282/13508) to a similar question (How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?). It's an ugly hack but... :)

Comment: @eggyal expecting answer from you brother

Answer (score 1):

Simple yet effective

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Answer (score -1):

You must first *fetch* the IDs, and *then* perform the update.  If concurrency is a concern, you can use a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) (provided that your table is stored in a transactional engine, such as InnoDB):

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$select = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM table WHERE yyy = ? FOR UPDATE');
$select->bind_param('s', $y);
$select->execute();

$update = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE table SET xxx = ? WHERE yyy = ?');
$update->bind_param('ss', $x, $y);
$update->execute();

$mysqli->commit();

// here are the IDs that were updated
$select->bind_result($id);
while ($select->fetch()) printf('Updated id: %s\n', $id);
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think of is to first sleect rows that would be updated with the update statement, those are:

```
$updatableIds = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE xxx !='".$x."' AND yyy='".$y."'");
```

we add `xxx !='".$x."'` because if value of `xxx` already was `$x` those rows would not be affected.

Next you run the update

```
$sql = mysqli_query("update table set xxx='".$x."' where yyy='".$y."'");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE users
SET type = '3'
WHERE type = '2';
```

To find out the last affected row right after the statement, it should be slightly updated as follows:

```
UPDATE users
SET type = '3',
    user_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(user_id)
WHERE type = '2';
```

// use function

```
 function updateAndGetId($value)
   {
       $query ="UPDATE users
    SET type = '$value',
        user_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(user_id)
    WHERE type = '2'";
      mysql_query($query)
    return mysql_insert_id();
   }
   $lastUpdatedRow = updateAndGetId(3);
```

In case you want to update only really changed row, add a conditional update of the user_id through the `LAST_INSERT_ID` and check if the data is going to change in the row.