# How to get IDs of the last updated rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the IDs of last update.

I have tried this.[How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

My code is

```
SET @uids := NULL;
UPDATE core_parcel 
    SET core_parcel.promotion_sms = '0'
WHERE core_parcel.senderid = '23'  AND core_parcel.promotion_sms = '1'
    AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(', ', @uids, core_parcel.REFID) )
LIMIT 10;
SELECT @uids;
```

But gives all id not just 10 ids. And it does not update at all.

```
AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(', ', @uids, core_parcel.REFID) )
```

Leaving out it updates.

Comment: Do you have an `updated_at` row in your table?

Comment: no updates are happened.

Comment: Then what are you gonna select?

Comment: I don't have any updated_at column. So, time stamp or something like this will not work. 

I want to select ids of updated column using query.

Comment: Well, you can't determine the last updated columns if there's nothing keeping track of it