# OUTPUT INSERTED also working for UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `pages` with the following fields:

- page_id
- f_page_object_id
- deactivation_date
- deactivation_editor
- is_published

When I want to deactivate a page, I need the f_page_object_id returned to be able to edit the connected row of a different table too.

I tried using OUTPUT INSERTED, but it does not seem to work (giving syntax error). I was wondering if I am using it right and it is even possible here:

```
UPDATE `pages` SET deactivation_date = '2016-01-14 16:10:31', deactivation_editor = 'test', is_published = '0' 
OUTPUT INSERTED.f_page_object_id
WHERE page_id = 291;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `OUTPUT`. You have to `SELECT` the value back out. You could create a stored procedure to wrap both actions.

Comment: Looks like there is a trick used by a few: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql

Comment: @JNevill This does indeed seem to work, but MySQL does not return a value from the bottom SELECT statement from the first example? If I ask for a result, it returns as false?

Comment: @Abayob Are you sure this is mysql question and not mssql one?