# Showing the last inserted or last updated row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a check-in / check-out system which writes for every check-in a new row in my table and updates the table when the person checks out (like checkedout = 1)

Now I'm making a new site that always shows the newest checked in person. I do it by polling and storing the highest ID on a variable on that page. In the polling I search for entries > the id i stored. It's working good so far.

But now I want to extend it and show either the latest checked in person OR the latest checked out person. How can I get the last "updated" row in my table?

Comment: column order by DESC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a column for ex. `date_checked` of type datetime and update it whenever something happens.

After that just select by that column.

Comment: Right! Sometimes the easiest solutions are hardest to think of :D thanks!

Comment: Create this field with `date_checked TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and MySQL will do almost all the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

use mysql function called mysqli_insert_id() which will give you last inserted primary key value of the table

Comment: This wont help with updated rows. I am using this for new entries.

Comment: then use datatype called as timestamp under sql store update date and time. while fetching check with latest time and date then fetch the records.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE some_table SET column_name = 'value', id = (SELECT @update_id := id)
WHERE some_other_column = 'blah' LIMIT 1; 
SELECT @update_id;
```

More [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751282/4896949)