# UPDATE on mysql python always returns 0 as lastrowid

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
def insert_ip_info(instance):
# Cursor to db
cur = db.cursor()

int_ipaddr = ipaddress_string_to_int(instance.ip_address)  # converting the string into unsigned integer

# Check if IP address exits in table (stores results from previous scan)
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM " + ip_info_table_name + " WHERE ip_address = " + str(int_ipaddr)
cur.execute(sql_query)
ip_exists = len(
    cur.fetchall())  # Using the len of the results only, to determine if the IP address exists in the table

if (ip_exists > 0):  # The IP address is already found in the table
    # Update the IP address information in the table
    sql_query = "UPDATE " + ip_info_table_name + \
                " SET hostname = %s , ip_location_id = %s WHERE ip_address = " + str(int_ipaddr)
    sql_data = (instance.hostname, instance.ip_location_id)

else:

    # Write a new line into db
    sql_query = "INSERT INTO " + ip_info_table_name + \
                " (ip_address,hostname,ip_location_id) " + \
                "VALUES(%s,%s,%s);"
    sql_data = (str(int_ipaddr), instance.hostname, instance.ip_location_id)
cur.execute(sql_query, sql_data)
cur.execute('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')
res = cur.fetchone()

cur.execute('SELECT @@identity')
res2 = cur.fetchone()
print cur.lastrowid
print db.insert_id()
print res
print res2
db.commit()
```

Here is the database:

```
Column  Type    Comment
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
ip_address  int(10) unsigned     
hostname    varchar(256) NULL    
ip_location_id  int(11) NULL     
Indexes
PRIMARY id
INDEX   ip_location_id
```

When I make the INSERT operation everything works like a charm,
but when I try the UPDATE operation all 4 tries (prints) fail (print 0).
I don't have any idea what I made wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
cur.execute('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')
```

This line says it all. However you request it, what you are looking at is the auto-incremented value of the last record ***inserted***. When you do an update, the auto-increment value for that index has not changed and so there is no value generated for the current query.

It's only valid when you have inserted a new row. If you want to obtain this value otherwise then you can either select max(id) or interrogate the schema but there's really very little point in doing so.

Comment: according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-lastrowid.html       it should be updated in UPDATE operaion as well

Comment: It encapsulates mysql_insert_id():
"Use this function after you have performed an INSERT statement into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT field, or have used INSERT or UPDATE to set a column value with LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)." Since your update didn't (I assume) use the SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID to set its value then the result will be zero.

Comment: so how can I get the last updated id ? max(id) is irrelevant because the UPDATE can be to any row

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql