# MySQL - Can user-defined variables be read by all scripts called by cron job?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm defining variables in the following way, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql?#answer-1751282) :

```
$sql = "SET @update_id := '', @update_name := '';
            UPDATE table SET status=?, id=(SELECT @update_id:=id), name=(SELECT @update_name:=name)
            WHERE status=? AND id>? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(1, 0, $curRow));
```

and then accessing them in a successive query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT @update_id, @update_blogid');
$stmt->execute();
```

This is used to mark a row while it is being updated. The table is large, and so there are a couple simultaneous scripts running, to help speed it up.

If the scripts are identical, but on two different processes initiated by a cron job, do they have access to each other's user-defined variables?

For instance, could a second process update the values set by the first process, before the first process was able to read the values?

[According to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

> User-defined variables are session-specific. A user variable defined
>   by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients.

So maybe the root of the question is: are two separate processes, initiated by the same cron job, considered separate clients?

Otherwise, my best thought is to initialize a random number when the script opens, and tack it to the end of each variable name:

```
$rand = rand(100, 999);

$sql = "SET @update_id". $rand ." := '', @update_name". $rand ." := ''; ...";
```

But would prefer not to, if I can help it. Even if the messy fix solves it, the answer to this will be good knowledge to have in the back pocket.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So many the root of the question is: are two separate processes, initiated by the same cron job, considered separate clients?

Yes. It would be no different than running two separate scripts initiated by the same browser. Unless you are explicitly sharing information between the two scripts, then they are executed as separate sessions.