# SQL get ID of row on which update is performed on the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I want to get the `ID` of the row on which an `UPDATE` function is being performed in the same SQL query.

Something like this:

```
Select id 
from relations 
where (UPDATE relations set x1 ='0', y1='0' WHERE element_from='abc')
```

I know this can be done by two separate queries but is there a way to get it in one single query?

Columns in table:

```
id_main     
id      
type        
x1      
y1      
x2      
y2      
element_from        
element_to      
d       
session     
name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain  it  by the related select

```
 select id from  relations  WHERE element_from='abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below (Idea taken from [How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql))

```
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE relations set x1 = '0', y1 = '0', id = (SELECT @update_id := id)
WHERE element_from = 'abc';
SELECT @update_id;
```