# Unable to fetch result on Multi MYSQL query statement

Tags: php, mysql

== SOLVED ==

I get this query from the following post:

[How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql)

I tried it on phpMyAdmin and see the result I wanted but unable to fetch it.

```
$query = "SET @order_id := '', @order_token := '', @order_param := ''; UPDATE transaction set `ts_status` = 'completed', `ts_remarks` = '', `tsid` = (SELECT @order_id := tsid), `token` = (SELECT @order_token := token), `param` = (SELECT @order_param := param) WHERE `token` = '503cd5c095fa942dbdfe72b2f4302edf' LIMIT 1; SELECT @order_id as order_id, @order_token as order_token,  @order_param as order_param";

if($result = $con->query($query)){
  $row = $result->fetch_array();
} else {
 echo 'no result';
}
```

It returns 'no result'

[image]

Please advise.

== SOLUTION ==

```
if (!$con->multi_query($query)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $con->store_result()) {
        $row = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($con->more_results() && $con->next_result());
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: SELECT. It's a multiple statement.

Comment: Most PHP MySQL APIs don't do multi-statements…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making one query for each statement. One for SET, one for UPDATE, one for SELECT.

ETA: That wouldn't work because of the SET I guess. You need to use [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I used multi_query as you suggested