# Update a row if exists otherwise insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'match' like

```
id|user1|user2|paired
--+-----+-----+--------+
1 |U_1  |null |false
```

I need to match a new user 'U_2' to a record where paired = false, or create a new entry in table if no unpaired row is found.

This db is connected to a server where multiple users might be trying to get paired, so I need to find best possible solution that makes it fast so it doesn't lock the table for long.

the solution I came up with was

```
int matchId = select id from match where ((user1 != 'U_2') AND (paired = false));

if(matchId > 0)
then
   update table match set user2 = 'U_2' where id = matchId; 
else
   insert new row.
```

Please suggest a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your existing solution looks fine to me. This looks very simple, are you seeing a specific performance issue here?

Comment: thank you for replying. I wanted to know if there was a batter way to do this. When looking up in a very large table querying database 2 times might increase response time. And there is also a possibility of 2 or more users getting same id from 1st query. and then so they might end up updating same row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can

- add unique indices for user1 and user2 to improve speed and assure integrity.
- use Transaction to avoid collisions.
- combine the select and update query in one update:

  ```
  update table match 
  set user2 = 'U_2' 
  where ((user1 != 'U_2') AND (paired = false)) 
  LIMIT 1;
  ```
- check if the update has [affected rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html). If not, insert the new row.

If i understand your intension properly, you can also:

- remove the column `paired`, it seems to be redundant, since it is always `false` when `user2=null`

Comment: but both users can be paired for any number of times. And also this way i won't be able to send data from updated row to user requesting match up..  or is there a way for this too?

Comment: I agree with code_angel's answer. Use update and insert if no affected rows. If update succeeded, just get the information with a select (use a timestamp to get the latest record for that user) OR check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql) thread to get the id directly from the update.

Comment: When multiple matches should be allowed, then as S. Roose said, use an additional timestamp column for a match. You can make the unique key over the user1, user2 and timestamp. Or just over user1 and timestamp. It's depend on details.

Comment: tried it and it worked fine, thanx a bunch. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Be sure to put both the update and insert in the same transaction.

Answer (score 3):

A single statement does one or the other:

```
INSERT INTO match
    (user1, paired, user2)
    VALUES
    ('U_2', false, 'U_2')   -- either insert this
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    user2 = VALUES(user2);  -- or update this
```

Together with

```
PRIMARY KEY(user1, paired)  -- a UNIQUE key to control what is "DUPLICATE"
```

Comment: Not for this case. There is a many-to-many relation. It was not exactly defined what the OP means with `insert new row.` in the question. But from the context and comments below my answer, it is clear: `both users can be paired for any number of times`