# How to get ID of the last inserted row in MySQL and Go?

Tags: mysql, go

How can I use this trick: [How to get ID of the last updated row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql) in Go (golang)?

I am using the go-sql-driver. It should work with these two queries but how can I do it in Go?

```
INSERT INTO table (unique_id) VALUES ("test")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Working solution. It is as simple as that. I hope someone else will find this useful:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT table SET unique_id=? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)")

res, err := stmt.Exec(unique_id)

lid, err := res.LastInsertId()
```

Comment: I have a similar case in which the primary key of my table is varchar(36) which contains a uuid values generated by trigger with the each new insertion .
I am updating an already existing code so the primary key was auto increament int value which used with LastInsertedRow , now i need to edit this so i added an additional column id_tracker which is an autoincreament column but not a primary key .
is it possible to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
UPDATE items
SET qwe = 'qwe',
    item_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(item_id)
WHERE asd = 'asd';
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```