# Laravel Update get updated ids

Tags: mysql

If I have Laravel eqoquent model (or pure mysql) And i try to update 10 records:

```
UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE is_admin IN (2,3);
```

How will I know which records are updated.

Is there any function in MySQL that will return the updated ids.

I need them

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: This is not thread save. If multiple threads(processes) uses one connection it is not save

Comment: I need to show the user which records are updated for example.

Comment: I would recommend not sharing one connection (at the same time) between multiple threads as that is generally regarded unsafe in of itself. If the connection is closed and put back into a pool and then later reused for a different thread that is different as only one thread is using the session at one time.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no function in mysql that would return the ids of the records that got updated. Why? Becsuse you already know which records you want to update: those that correspond to the `where` criteria of your `update` query. There is only a function that tells you [how many records got affected](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) by your query.

If you want to know exactly which records got updated by your query, then you need to query the fields and ids of the records that could be updated before the update and then compare the values after the update. Where the values got changed, those are the records that got updated.

Alternatively, you can add a timestamp column to the table, which gets modified if a record is updated. After the update you can query which records got updated.

Comment: I know the wanted behaviour? Yes i do, but I want to know which records are updated? And i need the ids

Comment: This leads to 3 queries and logic for comparing all over the place, in PostGre you have RETURNING id; which is more than cool. But in MySQL....

Comment: You can try the solutions suggested in the duplicate topic proposal by ThatGuyInIT if you insists.

Comment: Thank you. Will try, just why it has to be so hard in mysql than postgre

Comment: You do not typically need to know which records got updated, so I can understand why this is not a priority for mysql.

Comment: Why not, If i get the rows and then update these are 2 queries, if I only update its 1. This is 50% performance less, why is not priority issue?

Comment: Because most of the times you are simply not interested in knowing exactly which records got updated.

Comment: I dont know, if i want to send email which records are updated i should make comparing logic which could be avoided simply if RETURNING id was in mysql

Comment: Just because you have a use case for this feature does not meant that everybody else does. Plus there are workarounds, so the priority is understandably low.

Comment: Maybe yes, but i am sure many has this issue. If not they they wouldn't implement it in PostGre

Comment: You could do a SELECT of the IDs that match your query into a temp table. Then use a UPDATE state with a join to the temp table to update only the records in the temp table. Lastly query the temp table.

Comment: One drawback of the above method is if a user deletes a row to be updated between the time the temp table is created and the update is run, the update won't update a deleted row; however, the temp table will have the id of the deleted record.

Comment: Yeah drawback and more code. I only say that these drawbacks could've been avoided if mysql just add the RETURNING keyword like postgre or something.