# `@` Symbol in mysql variable names

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have started maintaining  a bunch of mysql stored procs. Some variables (created with decalare statements) are accessed with the @ symbol and others without it. Whats the difference

Comment: and why does the title of this question starts wiht "stored procedures" instead of "mysql", as it is clearly the more important tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable with the **@** at the beginning is session variable. It exists until the [session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)  end.