# Query works in Workbench but returns error in ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, freeradius

I've created a stored procedure for accessing accounting data from FreeRADIUS, which has been tested in MySQL Workbench and runs fine, but when running as a cfquery/cfstoredproc I get the error 'Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE'.

I have checked the driver is set up for MySQL 4/5 (the database is MySQL 5) and have tried copying and pasting the call from MySQL Workbench and running without using cfqueryparam as shown below but it still returns the same error.

The stored procedure was created with

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE radius.GetUserDataUsageForMonth(IN StartDate DATE, IN EndDate DATE, IN UserName     
VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

SET @records = (SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM `radius`.`radacct` WHERE userName = @UserName AND AcctStartTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) - 1;

SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT SUM(AcctOutputOctets) AS BytesIN, SUM(AcctInputOctets) AS BytesOUT FROM
        (SELECT * FROM `radius`.`radacct` WHERE userName = @UserName AND AcctStartTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate LIMIT ? 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT * FROM `radius`.`radacct` WHERE userName = @UserName AND AcctStartTime < @StartDate ORDER BY AcctStartTime DESC LIMIT 1) AS Totals;';

PREPARE stmt FROM @SqlQuery;
EXECUTE stmt USING @records;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

To call this I am using:

```
<cfquery name="qRadAccount_currentData" datasource="#application.datasource_radius#">
    CALL radius.GetUserDataUsageForMonth('2011-06-01','2011-07-01','ryan.french');
</cfquery>
```

I have also tried

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="radius.GetUserDataUsageForMonth" datasource="#application.datasource_radius#" result="qRadAccount_currentData">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="2011-06-01">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="2011-07-01">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="ryan.french">
</cfstoredproc>
```

Comment: Are you sure your data connection is pointing to the correct DB schema?

Comment: It works for me with CF9/mySQL5.1.42. But are all the variables accounted for in your `EXECUTE stmt USING ...` statement? That is one cause of the `Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE` error. http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html

Comment: @Leigh Yeah I'm pretty sure they are. Calling the routine from MySQL Workbench works fine. It's only when I move the query to my CF9 install that I get the error.

Comment: @Limey Yep, the datasource should be fine as we use it in other more simple queries.

Comment: @Ryan - Just for grins, do you still get the error if you comment out the dynamic sql part and just run the basic proc shell? ie `CREATE PROCEDURE radius.GetUserDataUsageForMonth(IN StartDate DATE, IN EndDate DATE, IN UserName   
VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
   
END`

Comment: If the error goes away, it is something in the procedure sql. Add back the statements one at time. See if you can pinpoint which one triggers the error. Otherwise, the problem is something else.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks, taking the dynamic sql out stopped the error, however it still strikes me as odd that it runs in workbench but not cfml. For now, I took the query out of the stored proc and am just running it in a cfquery by itself, and it works fine.

Comment: @Ryan - Possibly a driver issue..? But did you try adding back the statements one at a time. See if you can pinpoint the causal statement. (May not apply to you, but I also saw this issue http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33851)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused in the line

```
SET @records = (SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM `radius`.`radacct` WHERE userName = @UserName AND AcctStartTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) - 1;
```

When run as a query, this would return the correct value, however when the values are passed in as a stored procedure from ColdFusion, the result was -1 (no rows were found from the query).

I mostly deal in MS SQL, but I believe that in MySQL the @ symbol defines a local or session variable. As a result, when calling from ColdFusion the variable did not exist, resulting in the error.

I replaced the line above with

```
SET @records = (SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM `radius`.`radacct` WHERE userName = UserName AND AcctStartTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate) - 1;
```

and calling the stored procedure returned the correct result.

Comment: Ohh.. you are right about @ being for session variables (I am more of an ms sql person too) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference/1010042#1010042 But are you sure `WHERE userName = UserName` is really working? I would think the variable and column name would need to be different ...

Comment: I've checked this against the results from running the query outside the stored procedure and it does look to be running fine.