# Select before and after rows around id with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the IDs around an ID with mySQL.

Example:

IDs ​​in the table:

```
2, 4, 5, 9, 11, 15, 19, 22, 25
```

I need to know the 5 IDs around the ID 9, for example.
The query should return:

```
4, 5, 9, 11, 15
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A possible solution would be to

- calculate the absolute value of each id where you subtract your ID.
- order the results and limit the resultset to 5 records.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT ABS(ID - 9), *
FROM   MyTable
ORDER BY
       ABS(ID - 9)
LIMIT  5
```

**Edit** *(thx to ypercube for pointing out a possible flaw in this solution)*

If the intent is to get 2 id's from the left and two id's from the right, the statement can be adjusted as follows

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID <= 9 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID > 9  ORDER BY ID ASC  LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Of course you mean `ORDER BY ABS(id - @id)` where `@id` is the specific id (`9` in the example)

Comment: @ypercube - thx, you are right offcourse. *I used the actual value because I believe the `@` is SQL Server syntax. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: OP is not clear on what he means with "the IDs around an ID" so this is one of the two possible senarios. For ids being: `4,5,6,7,8,9,23,47`, this query will show `5,6,7,8,9` which is fine (since OP's intentions are unclear). The other senario would be to show two ids from the left and two from the right: `7,8,9,23,47`

Comment: Regarding variables, it depends on how he is passing them (PHP, stored procedures, etc). A nice example with the different types of variables on MySQL: [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Comment: To get interval values, I added the clause `WHERE ABS(ID - 9) BETWEEN -3 AND 3` and remove `LIMIT 5`

Comment: @ypercube - <sigh> I seem to be needing a lot of help today </sigh>

Comment: No, your answer was 100% correct. I just added a performance improvement :)

Comment: Both of these queries produce a syntax error on MariaDB 10.3.23. The first one at the `*` sign, the second at the `UNION` keyword.