# Syntax error in mysql?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm used to MS sql so working with mySql is sure to throw some syntax error at me that is bound to slow me down. I have the following:

```
declare @expensesSum DOUBLE
select @expensesSum = sum(expenseAmount) from bondsaverdb.expenses
insert into bondsaverdb.expenses
select '6','Extracash',(income - @expensesSum)  from bondsaverdb.income where userName ='Dean'
```

The error I'm getting says:

> syntax error near declare @expensesSum

Must be the way I'm declaring the variable??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This'll help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Comment: What comes before this? You might be missing a delimiter `;` which MS SQL doesn't need but MySQL does.  Post the entire procedure this is a part of.

Comment: Hope u knew this "DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements".  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not require (or even allow, apparently) you to `declare` variables, and as far as I know it will treat all objects, variables included, as strings -- so they cannot be typed in t his way.  Anyway, this should work:

```
SET @expensesSum = (SELECT SUM(expenseAmount) FROM bondsaverdb.expenses);
INSERT INTO
   bondsaverdb.expenses
SELECT
   '6', 'Extracash', (income - @expensesSum)
FROM
   bondsaverdb.income
WHERE
   userName = 'Dean'
```

I'm also not sure what that `'6'` is for .. if that's an auto increment ID you should omit it from the `INSERT` altogether (and specify the other columns to write to) or leave it `NULL`.

Comment: You can declare variables inside stored procedures.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand thanks, that could be useful if this is intended to be a stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is very different to SQL Server; you don't declare variables generally

```
SET @expensesSum = (select @expensesSum = sum(expenseAmount) from bondsaverdb.expenses);
insert into bondsaverdb.expenses
select '6','Extracash',(income - @expensesSum)  from bondsaverdb.income where userName ='Dean';
```