# What does @variable := variable2 mean in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query within inside a `select if` in my code and I can't remember what the line containing `@lastComment := time` actually does?

```
SELECT 
    IF(
        (SELECT @lastComment := `time` 
         FROM usermessages 
         WHERE userId = $userId 
         ORDER BY id DESC 
         LIMIT 1)
    IS NOT NULL,
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 SECOND) >= @lastComment, 1
    )
```

It looks like @lastComment is just a temporary variable holding time but I don't understand why it's needed, is it just to pass it to the other query?

Comment: This query is written awkwardly; it could be rewritten to be clearer in its intent.

Comment: good explanation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Comment: @p.campbell Yes that's what I intend to do now, just working out what the third line actually does is what's stopping me though

Comment: Looks like its examining the most recent 'usermessage' to see if its within 30seconds of now(). If it is, save the string 'time' into @lastcomment. It is awkward phrasing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you didn't want to execute the query twice and that's correct but you can easily omit the user-defined variable and thus make it clearer:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(
     (
       SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 SECOND) >= `time` 
       FROM usermessages 
       WHERE userId = $userId 
       ORDER BY id DESC 
       LIMIT 1
     )
     , 1
)
```

which translates to: *check if the given expression is NULL, if so return 1, else return the expression value.*