# MySQL local variables

Tags: mysql, database, set, local-variables, declare

I am trying to define and initialize a MySQL variable for a query.

I have the following:

```sql
DECLARE @countTotal INT;
SET @countTotal = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nGrams;
```

I am using MySQL in Netbeans and it tells me I have an error. What/where is my error?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

MySQL has two different types of variable:

- **local variables** (which *are not* prefixed by `@`) are strongly typed and scoped to the stored program block in which they are declared.  Note that, as documented under [`DECLARE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare.html):

  > [`DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare.html) is permitted only inside a [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.
- [**user variables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) (which *are* prefixed by `@`) are loosely typed and scoped to the session.  Note that they neither need nor can be declared—just use them directly.

Therefore, if you are defining a stored program and actually do want a "local variable", per the wording in your question, you will need to drop the `@` character and ensure that your `DECLARE` statement is at the start of your program block.  Otherwise, to use a "user variable", drop the `DECLARE` statement.

Furthermore, you will either need to surround your query in parentheses in order to execute it as a subquery:

```
SET @countTotal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nGrams);
```

Or else, you could use [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @countTotal FROM nGrams;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:-

```
 select @countTotal := COUNT(*) from nGrams;
```

Comment: I think you probably intended to use the [`:=` assignment operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value), rather than the [`=` equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal)?

Answer (score 4):

Function example:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test(in_number INT) RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE countTotal INT;
        SET countTotal = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nGrams;
    RETURN countTotal + in_number;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You're making a function or procedure?

Comment: [A subquery must always appear within parentheses.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/subqueries.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare.html), `declare` must be inside a begin...end block.

Answer (score -1):

You can set local variables with [DECLARE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1, v2 INT DEFAULT 2;       -- v1 and v2 are 2.
  DECLARE v3, v4 INT DEFAULT v1 + v2; -- v3 and v4 are 4.
  DECLARE result INT;                 -- result is NULL.
  SELECT v3 + v4 INTO result;         -- result is 8. 
  RETURN result;                      -- 8 is returned.
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

*Memos:

- You can initialize local variables with `DEFAULT`.
- The initial values of the local variables without `DEFAULT` are `NULL`.
- `DECLARE` block can be set within the top of [BEGIN ... END statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html) within the [stored programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/stored_programs.html) [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html), [procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html), [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) and [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).
- Local variables are deleted after the execution of stored programs.
- Local variables are not influenced by transaction so their changed values cannot be rollbacked. *[My question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77672844/a-local-variable-is-not-rollbacked-in-a-mysql-procedure) explain it in detail.

Then, `8` is returned as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT my_func();
+-----------+
| my_func() |
+-----------+
|         8 |
+-----------+
```

Be careful, if `DECLARE` block is not set within the top of `BEGIN ... END` statement within stored programs as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  SELECT 2 + 3;                       -- Because of this
  DECLARE v1, v2 INT DEFAULT 2;       -- Not the top
  DECLARE v3, v4 INT DEFAULT v1 + v2; -- Not the top
  DECLARE result INT;                 -- Not the top
  SELECT v3 + v4 INTO result;
  RETURN result;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Or:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1, v2 INT DEFAULT 2;
  DECLARE v3, v4 INT DEFAULT v1 + v2;
  SELECT 2 + 3;       -- Because of this
  DECLARE result INT; -- Not the top
  SELECT v3 + v4 INTO result;
  RETURN result;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, there is the error below:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...

Comment: This is a rant about/manual on `DECLARE` rather than an answer to the specific question asked. There was no need to post it 11 years later. Also please consider not [restyling other people's code according to your personal preference](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13670659/revisions).

Comment: @GSerg That is also your preference though. Be careful.

Comment: That this does not answer the question is not my personal preference, it is a fact. This "answer" even specifically avoids mentioning the only one single thing that the OP got wrong - which is correctly mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670710/11683). This is a blog post that belongs to your personal blog. Posting it here is specifically against the rules, which are not my personal preference here.

Comment: @GSerg You can also check other answers of this question with your preference. Go for it!!