# Stored function returns NULL Mysql

Tags: mysql, function, null

i make this simple STORED FUNCTION in MySql that returns emails sparated with comma:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_participantes (id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
 DECLARE par VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "";
 (select GROUP_CONCAT(mail SEPARATOR ',') INTO @par from users where id IN (
select user_id from meeting_participants where meeting_id = id));
 RETURN @par;
END
```

But when i call it using SELECT, i got NULL everytime. The SQL sentence works perfectly but itself.

```
+----------------------+
| get_participantes(5) |
+----------------------+
| NULL                 |
+----------------------+
```

Please help

Comment: Well what happens when you run the raw `select` query in MySQL, with the `id` value of 5 hard coded?  Do you get anything back?

Comment: Have you tried to run `select GROUP_CONCAT(mail SEPARATOR ',') from users where id IN (
select user_id from meeting_participants where meeting_id = 5)`???

Comment: YES, it worked. I solve it. Was the parameter that was ambiguous

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The name of your function parameter is `id`, but you also have a column `id` in your users table, and maybe there's an `id` column in your meeting_participants table as well.

This creates an ambiguity. The expression doesn't know whether you mean the column `id` or the function parameter `id`.

You should give your function parameter a distinct name, to resolve the ambiguity.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_participantes (_id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
 DECLARE par VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "";
 (select GROUP_CONCAT(mail SEPARATOR ',') INTO par from users where id IN (
select user_id from meeting_participants where meeting_id = _id));
 RETURN par;
END
```

---

A couple of other issues that you should know about, even though they are not related to your question:

1. In MySQL routines (unlike SQL Server for example), your `par` local variable is not the same as the `@var` session variable. Your code in this specific case will work, but it's possible some other function you write will be confused. See also my answer to ["@" symbol in stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323538/symbol-in-stored-procedure/15323806#15323806)
2. You should add the clause `READS SQL DATA` to your function, or else you may get this error (as I did when I tested your function):

> ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)