MySQL error Error [1064] [42000]... only when passing session variables into stored procedure
I'm primarily an MSSQL user, but need to do something for a client that uses MySQL, and am running into a very odd issue (while using DBeaver). I have the following procedure:
CREATE DEFINER=`myusr`@`%` PROCEDURE `mydb`.`udp_ClientApprovals_Display`(
    IN _BolSearchText varchar(100)
    , IN _BolManufSearchText varchar(100)
    , IN _ClientID int
    , IN _OrderBy varchar(50))
BEGIN
    SET @BolSearchText = _BolSearchText
        , @BolManufSearchText = _BolManufSearchText
        , @ClientID = _ClientID;
-- the rest of my code
END

Long story short: this works perfectly:
CALL udp_ClientApprovals_Display('+test*', '', 1, 'Name');

...but this returns "SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1" :
SELECT @BolSearchText := '+test*', @BolManufSearchText := '', @ClientID := 1, @OrderBy := 'Name';
CALL udp_ClientApprovals_Display(@BolSearchText, @BolManufSearchText, @ClientID, @OrderBy);


There's no NULL anywhere in the code you've shown. The error must be somewhere in -- the rest of my code.

Why are you using session variables inside the procedure? There could be an issue because the variables inside the procedure are the same as the ones in the caller. Session variables are not scoped like normal variables.

@Barmar: thanks for the response. The rest of the code consists of composing a lengthy dynamic query into a variable, followed by preparing a "stmt" variable, followed by EXECUTE stmt USING @BolSearchText, @BolManufSearchText, @ClientID;. I tried the EXECUTE stmt line without session variables, and it didn't work, so session variables it is.

You might be accustomed to the @ sigil used in Microsoft SQL Server for local variables and parameters. But MySQL is different; a variable with the @ sigil is a different variable than one spelled similarly without the sigil. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323538/symbol-in-stored-procedure/15323806#15323806

Right, EXECUTE requires the parameters to be session variables. Anyway, the problem is probably in the prepared statement. I don't know why you only get it when the procedure is called using session variables.

@BillKarwin Unfortunately, prepared statements requires the use of session variables.

Do you still have the problem if the variables you use in the caller are different from the ones in the procedure? I'm not sure why they would interfere, but I'm grasping at straws.

Yes, MySQL's EXECUTE USING statement only accepts session variables. This is the way the parser is implemented. See the yacc grammar here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/trunk/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L2588-L2606

Thanks both of you! Actually, the problem seems to have fixed itself... or maybe it's more that it's an issue on DBeaver's end. I've implemented it in PHP using mysqli (which was the end goal) and it seems to work there, so I think we're good? Not sure how to mark as answered without a real answer. But thanks again!
