# Inserting e-mail address in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The last few hours I've spent in struggling with a quite ridiculous error.
Simply what I'm making a registration form. User need to enter a e-mail and the mail will be stored in a mysql table. (I have to warn you - please disregard the security issue, the whole thing is just a exercise). But I constantly get the following error from the sql:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@gmail.com,blqh2@gmail.com,1)' at line 1

The html is as follows:

```
      <form method="post" action="createnew.php">
            <label >user name</label>
            <input name="login_id"></br>
            <label>password</label>
            <input name="password" password></br>
                    ...some more stuff...
            <label>Privet e-mail</label>
            <input name="prv_email"></br>
            <label>Public e-mail</label>
            <input name="pub_email"></br>
            <label>Are you a reseller</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="reseller"></br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Then comes the PHP:

```
$login_id=$_POST['login_id'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
...some more stuff...
$pub_email=$_POST['pub_email'];
echo $prv_email;
echo $pub_email;
if (array_key_exists('reseller',$_POST)) {
    $reseller=1;
}
else {
    $reseller=0;
}
$sql="INSERT INTO users".
    "(login_id,password,usr_phone,region,prv_email,pub_email,reseller)".
    "VALUES".
"($login_id,$password,$usr_phone,$region,$prv_email,$pub_email,$reseller)"
```

And finally the MySQL formatting for the mail field(practically they prv_email and pub_email are with the same formatting)

```
    Field     | Type         | Collation
    ----------|--------------|-------------------  
    pub_email | varchar(255) | utf8_general_ci
```

I did try a lot off stuff but nothing seems to work. It always crushes at @.
and one more thing - I'm running this who code on localhost(using WAMP), not sure if this have anything to deal with the problem.
Please let me know if you need any other information and thanks a lot.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Comment: do a `echo $sql;die();` after the $sql line. Then post that here.

Comment: Read more about the `@` and why your getting this error:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following:

```
"($login_id,$password,$usr_phone,$region,$prv_email,$pub_email,$reseller)"
```

will be parsed as literals, rendering it the error you see above. You'll need to wrap each variable in single quotes for it to be seen as a string value instead.

I'd recommend that you have a look at [PDO & Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), as PDO provides an abstraction layer towards the database, as well as great security (for example via Prepared Statements).

Additionally, you're inserting to the field `pub_email`, but from your given output in the post, it's supposed to be `pub_mail`.

Comment: aha, now i see. Thanks for the recommendations. I'm bit new in PHP but PDO is something that almost everyone is pushing me to have a look at, so this will be my next step. And, yes, it was a mistype :)

Comment: Enjoy the ride! @Alordiel :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to enclose your values in single quotes (') Change this snippet of code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users".
    "(login_id,password,usr_phone,region,prv_email,pub_email,reseller)".    "VALUES".
    "($login_id,'$password','$usr_phone','$region','$prv_email','$pub_email','$reseller')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to, at the very least, add `'`'s around the strings and do a [`mysql-real-escape-string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on all passed arguments.  Far better would be to use prepared statements with PDO or mysqli