# Mysql procedure increment variable

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm trying to get rank of user in the table with stored time.

RAW SQL query is working fine but I can't make it work as procedure.

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT rank, user_id, best_time
FROM (
  SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank,id, best_time, user_id
  FROM user_round WHERE round_id=1 ORDER BY best_time ASC
) AS result WHERE user_id = 1
```

My try to procedure:

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE variable INT DEFAULT 0;
 SELECT rank,best_time, user_id
 FROM (
  SELECT SET variable=variable+1 AS rank, best_time, user_id
  FROM database.user_round WHERE round_id=1 ORDER BY best_time ASC
 ) AS result WHERE user_id = 1;
END
```

Comment: Try removing `SET` from `SELECT SET variable=variable+1`

Comment: If i remove set I can save procedure but rank is always 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to continue using a [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html), not a [13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html):

```sql
BEGIN
    -- DECLARE variable INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT rank, best_time, user_id
    FROM (
        -- SELECT SET variable = variable + 1 AS rank, best_time, user_id
        SELECT @variable := @variable + 1 AS rank, best_time, user_id
        FROM database.user_round, (SELECT @variable := 0) init
        WHERE round_id = 1
        ORDER BY best_time ASC
    ) AS result
    WHERE user_id = 1;
END
```

Comment: In this case you may have to watch out for this: `The difference between a procedure variable and a session variable is that procedure variable is reinitialized to NULL each time the procedure is called, while the session variable is not` as mentioned at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1010042/

Comment: @AzizShaikh: That's right, so it initializes the variable `@variable` in each execution of the stored procedure. See `(SELECT @variable := 0) init`

Comment: why should we stick to user variables, since they would fail the query if the stored procedure is called simultaneously from two or more threads?