# SQL stored procedure, variable is null

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_exercise` (nazev VARCHAR(45), URL VARCHAR(255), obtiznost INT, partie INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE video_id INT;
    DECLARE cvik_id INT;

    INSERT INTO `odkaz_video` (URL) VALUES (@URL);
    SELECT id INTO video_id FROM `odkaz_video` WHERE URL = @URL;
    INSERT INTO `cvik` (nazev, odkaz_video, obtiznost_id) VALUES (@nazev, video_id, @obtiznost);
    SELECT id INTO cvik_id FROM `cvik` WHERE nazev = @nazev;
    INSERT INTO `cvik_partie` (partie_id, cvik_id) VALUES (@partie, cvik_id);
END
```

When I call this SP I get error 1048, Column 'URL' cannot be null. Why is this variable (@URL) null even though I typed in all parameters?

Thanks for the respond

Comment: You might also find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Comment: Can you please include the exact statement you are using to call the stored procedure, as well as the full table definitions of the tables involved?  It's possible the problem is either in the calling statement or the result of a key constraint in the table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the names as given in the procedure parameters:

CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_exercise` (**nazev** VARCHAR(45), **URL** VARCHAR(255), **obtiznost** INT, **partie** INT)

They are not prefixed with a **@**.

Check out this tutorial: [MySQL stored procedure parameters](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`@URL` is NULL because you never set its value. The input parameter is named `URL`, not `@URL`.

Furthermore I recommend that you prefix the parameter names with `p_` and the local variable names with `v_` to differentiate them from the column names.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_exercise` (p_nazev VARCHAR(45), p_URL VARCHAR(255), p_obtiznost INT, p_partie INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE v_video_id INT;
    DECLARE v_cvik_id INT;

    INSERT INTO `odkaz_video` (URL) VALUES (p_URL);
    SELECT id INTO v_video_id FROM `odkaz_video` WHERE URL = p_URL;
    INSERT INTO `cvik` (nazev, odkaz_video, obtiznost_id) VALUES (p_nazev, v_video_id, p_obtiznost);
    SELECT id INTO v_cvik_id FROM `cvik` WHERE nazev = p_nazev;
    INSERT INTO `cvik_partie` (partie_id, cvik_id) VALUES (p_partie, v_cvik_id);
END
```