# MySQL using last auto incremented ID from a table in other tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I currently have the following statements.

```
INSERT INTO TripsTaken (ProfileId, DestinationLocation, Name, ImageUrl, StartDate, EndDate, Summary, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
INSERT INTO Transportation(Type, Location, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
INSERT INTO TripsTakenTransportation (TripId, id) VALUES( (SELECT MAX(LAST_INSERT_ID()) FROM TripsTaken) , LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO Transportation(Type, Location, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
INSERT INTO TripsTakenTransportation (TripId, id) VALUES( (SELECT MAX(LAST_INSERT_ID()) FROM TripsTaken) , LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

I'm getting the following error:

> { [Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tripsdatabase`.`tripstakentransportation`, CONSTRAINT `tripstakentransportation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TripId`) REFERENCES `TripsTaken` (`TripId`))]
>     code: 'ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_',
>     errno: 1452,
>     sqlState: '23000',
>     index: 2 }

The error occurs whenever the statement `INSERT INTO TripsTakenTransportation...` occurs twice. I suspect my sub query `(SELECT MAX(LAST_INSERT_ID()) FROM TripsTaken)` is not doing what I expected the second time around.

How can I get the LAST_INSERT_ID() from a table, store it and reuse it in my other queries?

Note:

`Transportation` also has an auto increment column.

Comment: @Mate I might have missed something in reading the docs but I don't see a solution there to my problem.

Comment: convert (SELECT MAX(LAST_INSERT_ID()) FROM TripsTaken) to (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TripsTaken) or just use the primary key with auto increment in the case is not named ID

Comment: @rusben There are many connections to the DB so if the another user changes it while I am working with the value things will go wrong. LAST_INSERT_ID() is a per session value.

Comment: I think the query is wrong. Probably you will like to use sql variables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have endowed `LAST_INSERT_ID()` with more intelligence than it has. You can't say `MAX(LAST_INSERT_ID()) FROM table` because it isn't tied to a table.

Here's the sort of thing you need:

```
INSERT INTO TripsTaken 
       (ProfileId, DestinationLocation, Name, 
        ImageUrl, StartDate, EndDate, Summary, Latitude, Longitude) 
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

SET @tripsID := LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Transportation
       (Type, Location, StartDate, EndDate) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);

INSERT INTO TripsTakenTransportation 
       (TripId, id)
VALUES (@tripsID , LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the value of the very most recently incremented auto-increment column value. The good news is that there's a value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for every distinct connection to MySQL, so you can rely on it to be correct from SQL statement to statement within a connection. The bad news is you have be very careful not to edit your SQL code to add new INSERT statements, because they have the side-effect of changing `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.  Hack with care.

Comment: Good stranger, you just saved my weekend. This solved my issue. Thanks.