# SQL: Create table with term names (String containing years)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I would like to create a table (two columns, first is auto incremental) which contains the term names, e.g. "SS 2000" and "WS 2000/2001" (for summer and winter term).

I tried the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()
BEGIN
Declare @YearEnd integer;
SET @YearEnd = 2014;
Declare @YearFrom integer = @YearEnd - 100;
Declare @Term varchar = '';
while @YearFrom < @YearEnd Begin
    @Term = concat('SS ', @YearFrom);
  Insert into terms (term) VALUES @Term;
  Set @YearFrom = @YearFrom + 1;
End
END
```

but I already get an error in line 3: SQL query:

CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()
BEGIN
    Declare @YearEnd integer;

MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@YearEnd integer' at line 3

After reading the comments from Abishek and Stuart, I tried the following:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_terms$$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()
BEGIN
  DECLARE YearEnd INT;
  Declare YearFrom INT;
  Declare Term varchar(10);

  SET YearEnd = 2014;
  SET YearFrom = YearEnd - 100;
  SET Term= '';

WHILE (YearFrom < YearEnd) DO
  SET Term = concat('SS ', YearFrom);
  Insert into terms (term) VALUES (Term);
  Set YearFrom = YearFrom + 1;
 END WHILE;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

This results in just the DROP PROCEDURE command being successfully processed. Even when removing this line and changing the first lines to:

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()$$
 BEGIN
```

it doesn't work, the SQl console just writes "ERROR" and that's it....    :(

Comment: Just replace @YearEnd(all user variables) to YearEnd(to local variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a bunch of errors here

- You should use [procedure variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010042/314291)
- The Syntax for insert is `INSERT INTO Table(columns) VALUES(values);`
- You probably also want to insert the term, not the year end
- Your syntax for [while is wrong](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()
BEGIN
  DECLARE YearEnd INT;
  Declare YearFrom INT;
  Declare Term varchar(10);

  SET YearEnd = 2014;
  SET YearFrom = YearEnd - 100;
  SET Term= '';

  WHILE (YearFrom < YearEnd) DO
      SET Term = concat('SS ', YearFrom);
      Insert into terms (term) VALUES (Term);
      Set YearFrom = YearFrom + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14d97/6)

Comment: Stuart, I see that your code is working in SQLFiddle but when I copy it directly into my sql console, it throws the error:

SQL query:


CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()
BEGIN
  DECLARE YearEnd INT;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Check your use of delimiters - possibly you have used a delimiter of `;` - See avisheks answer for how to change delimiters.

Comment: Hi Stuart, I did so but this results in just the first command "DROP PROCEDURE" is being executed....

inline `    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_terms$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()
BEGIN
Declare YearEnd integer;
SET YearEnd = 2014;
Declare YearFrom integer = YearEnd - 100;
Declare Term varchar = '';
while YearFrom < YearEnd Begin
    Term = concat('SS ', YearFrom);
  Insert into terms (term) VALUES YearFrom;
  Set YearFrom = YearFrom + 1;
End;
END;
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: No, I meant just add `DELIMITER /` before you execute MY SqlFiddle answer on YOUR MySql server. On SqlFiddle, you change the Delimiter at the bottom drop down.

Answer (score 1):

All variable staring @ are user variables and need not to be declared, procedures has their local variables not prefix with @, try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_terms$$
CREATE PROCEDURE create_terms()
BEGIN
Declare YearEnd integer;
SET YearEnd = 2014;
Declare YearFrom integer = YearEnd - 100;
Declare Term varchar = '';
while YearFrom < YearEnd Begin
    Term = concat('SS ', YearFrom);
  Insert into terms (term) VALUES YearFrom;
  Set YearFrom = YearFrom + 1;
End;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference) is help

Comment: Hi Avishek, thanks for the clarification about the variable declaration. Now I do get error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: @AntonSack, Try updated answer, you had delimiter issue

Comment: Yes, that's it. Finally, the code is accepted BUT only the drop command is executed. Everything afterwards is just ignored...