# SQL Like statement with regular expressions

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

My table contains some columns with ;-separated numbers like this :

`1;2;43;22;20;12`

and so on. It's also possible there's only 1 number in this column like `110`, or 2 numbers like this `110;143`

I want to select the rows that contain a certain number in this column. The number is in a variable $search_var.
Let's say I need to search for the number 1 in my column. If I use a select with like statement like so :

`"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ids LIKE '%".$search_var."%'"`

I get all results containing '1' and not only '1', so I also get 11, 14, 110, 1999 etc. 
I think I need to use some sort of regex-statement but I'm lost here... Who can help ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Oracle? SQLite? MySQL?

Comment: I'm using Mysql, sorry forgot to mention !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not need regex for this

```
Set @YourNUmber := 110;

SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE ';' + ids + ';' LIKE '%;'+ @yourNumber + ';%'
```

This guarantees there are always `;` surrounding all the numbers.

This is formatted for SQL Server. The variable syntax and wildcards might be different if you are using something else.

EDIT:

Thanks @FélixGagnon-Grenier for the suggestions. I think either of these two will work. See here for a [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a4e5/24)

```
SELECT * 
FROM T 
WHERE concat(';',ids,';') LIKE concat('%;', @YourNumber , ';%');


SELECT * 
FROM T 
WHERE LOCATE(concat(';', @YourNumber , ';'),concat(';',ids,';'))>0
```

Comment: Any help on how to transforms this to MySQL ?

Comment: I don't know mySQL to answer definitively enough. You could try the answers here through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference  Does it not work as written? (just curious)

Comment: `SET` does not take `:` before the `=`, this is when defining variables with `SELECT`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier So it should be like that? (edited) The example in my above comment uses `:=` with `SET`

Comment: @Brad it does indeed. but it does not work. and mysql reference does not agree: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html also be sure to put a `;` between different statements, this code would generate an error.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier nice. thanks for the tips. How's the edit look?

Comment: Almost perfect, just get the initial `Set` to `SELECT` once again and that's it :)

Comment: got it thanks to this answer : `WHERE concat(';',Table,';') LIKE concat('%;', '".$search_var."' , ';%')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if you're using SQL Server. This searches for the number where adjcent characters are not numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ids LIKE '%[^0-9]".$search_var."[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: What RDBMS allows regular expressions in LIKE clauses?  Most of them have a separate function for that.  Also, your example fails if `Name` is *only* a number with no padding around it.

Comment: Edited the table and column name. This works with SQL Server. Read this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx