# Difference between declare @variablename and declare variablename while working with stored procedures

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I wanted to know what is the difference between `@variablename` and `variablename`. All the help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 2):

```
variablename
```

Local variables

Local variables are declared within stored procedures and are only valid within the BEGIN…END block where they are declared. Local variables can have any SQL data type.

```
@variablename
```

User variables

In MySQL stored procedures, user variables are referenced with an ampersand (@) prefixed to the user variable name (for example, @x and @y). You can store a value in a user-defined variable in one statement and then refer to it later in another statement. This enables you to pass values from one statement to another. User-defined variables are session-specific. That is, a user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. All variables for a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits.

In MySQL the variable var1 and @var1 are two different things. @var1 is a user session variable which remains for the duration of the active session. The other is local to the stored procedure.