# Purpose of @ in Mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm new to mysql and I don't understand the purpose of the **@** in the following code, if someone could explain to me the next piece of code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  INREGISTRARE_CLIENT;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE INREGISTRARE_CLIENT(_nume char(20), _prenume char(20), _adresa_id int, _sex int)

BEGIN
   SET @is_adresa_id = NULL;
   SELECT @is_adresa_id := id FROM adresa;
   IF (@is_adresa_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO client_card_fidelitate (nume, prenume, adresa_id, sex, data_inregistrare) VALUES
                   (_nume, _prenume, _adresa_id, _sex, CURRENT_DATE());
   END IF;
END //
IDELIMITER ;
```

Comment: [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: Check the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html

Comment: They are user-defined variables. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Comment: I don't understand why is my question downvoted...what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the syntax to use variable in MySQL.
For example: SET @a = 1;//this means the @a variable is set to value 1.