# what does this symbol mean := in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, colon-equals

What does this mean

> :=

in sql ?

If found some sql using like that symbol example

```
select col1, col2, @pv:=col3 as 'col3' from table1
join
(select @pv:=1)tmp
where col1=@pv
```

Comment: [`:=`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) is assignment operator.

Answer (score 14):

using this: here variable are prepended with an @ sign to suggest `user-defined variable.`A variable, without @, is a system variable, which you cannot define yourself.

```
SET  @pv:=1// we set a variable
```

i.e `:=` is used as assignment operator like normal `=` else where.

see here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

and also see a good post here:[MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Comment: Thank you.what about the @ ?

Comment: @ashTon @ sign to suggest user-defined variable.