# An error in MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

Why the stored procedure can't be created?

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN
DECLARE j INT;
SET j = 1;
SELECT j:=j+1, request.* FROM request;
END//
```

The problem is in line:

```
SET j:=j+1, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a @ to the variable name:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN
SET @j = 1;
SELECT @j:=@j+1, request.* FROM request;
END//
```

Here's an explanation: [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Comment: So if i understand correctly, i can't change procedure-local variables this way?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The problem is just in the increment you give inside the select, otherwise you could do SET j = 1; SET j = j +1; SELECT j, ...